# Libgdx | Where to put proguard-rules.pro file?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am using libgdx, and it is time for me to export my game as an apk. I heard I should use proguard, so I tried to set it up. The problem is that no matter where I look, and I can't find out where to place my proguard-rules.pro file. Keep in mind that my project structure is libgdx style. Should I store it in my assets directory? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you used libGDX Project Generator which creates a gradle project, you can find a file called `build.gradle` under your `android` folder.

Inside your `android/build.gradle` file you need to edit the android plugin parameters adding your `signingConfigs` and `buildTypes`.
Then this file should look something like this:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        ...
    }
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    signingConfigs {
        releaseSigning {
            storeFile file('../thisisyour.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'release'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled true will turn proguard ON
            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles let you add your own proguard rules ('proguard-project.txt') in this case, as its already created by gdx-setup
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseSigning
        }
    }
```

Finally, place your custom rules (if needed) at bottom of `android/proguard-project.txt` file.

Then, when generating the distributable APK, run `gradlew assemblerelease`

Comment: But I don't understand where to find the proguard-app-rules.pro file. I don't see it anywhere :

Comment: There is a file called proguard-project.txt though.